# Why 'Code is not sufficiently generic'?

Tags: generics, f#, inline, type-inference

Can anyone explain why the second example below won't compile?

'Test 2' gives "error FS0670: This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable  ^a could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.". I fail to understand this error message.

```
// Test 1
type test1<'a> = | A of 'a 
  with
    override t.ToString() = 
      match t with
      | A a -> a.ToString()

// Test 2
type test2<'a> = | A of 'a 
  with
    override t.ToString() = 
      match t with
      | A a -> string a

// Test 3
type test3<'a> = | A of 'a 
  with
    override t.ToString() = 
      match t with
      | A a -> string (a :> obj)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another repro:

```
let inline f< ^T>(x:^T) = box x

type test4<'a> = | A of 'a  
  with 
    member t.M() =  
        match t with
        | A a -> f a
```

`string` is an inline function that uses static type constraints, and the error diagnostics for such functions are sometimes poor.  I don't really understand the diagnostic message itself, but the point is, at the call site, we don't know the generic type `'a`, which means we can't inline the right version of the call to `string` (or `f` in my repro).  In e.g. the case where you upcast to `obj`, we know that we want to inline the `obj` version of `string`, so that is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's because string has a signature of (obj -> string) so using string on its own is forcing a to be of type obj. (F# doesn't do implicit casts.)

Comment: `string` [is in fact `'T -> string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee340491.aspx), so this should work in theory. I don't have a better explanation for the error though.

Comment: Oh yes, I just stuck string;; into F# interactive to get the type.
Presumably actually using string is forcing the compile to force a type on the input, and it's choosing obj as the lowest common denominator?